# Setting multiple values on SQL update in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a very simple ASPX page that has one textbox and one button. When a user inputs an [ID] number, it automatically adds a date/time stamp to that corresponding row [ShipDate] in SQL. Now, what I'm needing to do, in addition to that, is to set another column [ScanQty] (and corresponding row) to count how many times that ID has been submitted. So, the first time it's submitted, it sets that corresponding row and it's column to 1, the next time, 2, and so needs to increase incrementally by 1.

I'm not sure that my code is really efficient, but it works. Right now, when the person inputs the [ID] and [ShipDate] is null, it adds a date/time stamp to [ShipDate]. If a person scans an [ID] that already has a value in [ShipDate], it tells them that it's already been marked as shipped. If an [ID] is scanned that isn't found in the system, it tells them. I need the incremental count to count in the first two scenarios when it doesn't have a ship date value and even when it does.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sql = @"SELECT ID from ProductTracking where ID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' and ShipDate is null";

            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if(reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        string sql2 = @"UPDATE [ProductTracking] SET ShipDate=@Value2 where ID=@Value1";
                        using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, connection))
                        {
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", TextBox1.Text);
                            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", DateTime.Now);
                            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        pageBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "#9aff8e");
                        Label1.Text = "Item " + TextBox1.Text + " Recorded!";
                        TextBox1.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        string sql3 = @"SELECT ID from ProductTracking where ID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";

                        using(SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, connection))
                        {
                            using(SqlDataReader reader2 = command3.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (reader2.HasRows)
                                {
                                    pageBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "#fbff8e");
                                    Label1.Text = "Item " + TextBox1.Text + " Already Shipped!";
                                    TextBox1.Text = "";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    pageBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "#ff8e8e");
                                    Label1.Text = "Item " + TextBox1.Text + " Not Found!";
                                    TextBox1.Text = "";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want ? its hard to read the whole story..

Comment: The whole point of a `using` block is you don't need the `finally` any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this down to a single trip out to the database. This is better, even when you have to run two commands in the same trip.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT ShipDate FROM [ProductTracking] WHERE ID= @ProductID;UPDATE [ProductTracking] SET ShipDate = current_timestamp, ScanQty = coalesce(ScanQty,0) + 1 WHERE ID= @ProductID";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  TextBox1.Text;
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
           if (!rdr.Read())
           {
               pageBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "#ff8e8e");
               Label1.Text = "Item " + TextBox1.Text + " Not Found!";
           }
           else if (rdr["ShipDate"] == DBNull.Value)
           {
                pageBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "#9aff8e");
                Label1.Text = "Item " + TextBox1.Text + " Recorded!";
           }
           else
           {
               pageBody.Attributes.Add("bgcolor", "#fbff8e");
               Label1.Text = "Item " + TextBox1.Text + " Already Shipped!";                 
           }
           rdr.Close();
        }
    }
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

I also wonder why the original code used string concatenation when it also demonstrates parameterized queries. It's **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to put a value into an SQL query, *even when the value is just an int*. You understand when someone hasn't encountered parameterized queries yet, but once you know how to use them, it's unprofessional to keep doing string concatenation anywhere else.